# Spring Boot OAuth2 - Keycloak - multiple realms for different endpoints

Tags: keycloak, openid, multi-tenant

I have a problem with multiple realms usage with Spring Boot and Keycloak.

I configure OAuth2 in my application with 2 realms like this:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realmuser
      client:
        provider:
          realmuser:
            props: ...

          realmadmin:
            props: ...

        registration:
          realmuser:
            props: ...

          realmadmin:
            props: ...
```

I have several endpoints in my application covered by Spring Security.

When I make a request to any of them I get Spring OAuth2 login page where I'm proposed to choose "realmuser" or "realmadmin" to login. After that everything works OK.

But my goal is to divide endpoints by realms.

For example, I'd like endpoints "/v1/admin/etc.." to be redirected to "realmadmin" and endpoints "/v1/user/etc.." to be redirected to "realmuser" immediately, i.e. without Spring OAuth2 login page.

Is there any way to achiveve this?

My SecurityConfig:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v1/*")
        .hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
    http.oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
  }
```

What I tried to do:

- Resolving the Tenant By Claim with JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver like described in docs.spring.io - Multinenancy OAuth 2.0 Resource Server
- Using annotation @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient
- Updating SecurityConfig with

```
    http.oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
        oauth2Login
            .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint ->
                authorizationEndpoint
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/authorization")
                    .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver("/oauth2/authorization/realmuser",
                        "/oauth2/authorization/realmadmin", clientRegistrationRepository()))
            )
    )
```

and then creating class

```
{

CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver

//...


    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String authorizationUri;
      if (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/v1/admin")) {
        authorizationUri = adminAuthorizationUri;
      } else if (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/v1/user")) {
        authorizationUri = userAuthorizationUri;
      } else {
        authorizationUri = "/oauth2/authorize";
      }
      OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
      return authorizationRequest != null ? OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
          .authorizationUri(authorizationUri)
          .build() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
      return defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request, clientRegistrationId);
    }

}
```

None of them helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client and resource server configurations are very different: requests to OAuth2 clients are secured with sessions, when those to resource server are secured with access tokens (which makes it possible to get rid of sessions).

`oauth2Login`, `logout` and all `spring.security.oauth2.client` properties are client features. In the configuration above, session are enabled and required for client configuration. **Disabling CSRF protection on an OAuth2 client is very unsafe and should not be done**.

If you inspect the requests sent by your browser, you won't find any access token. You'll just find session cookies. You'd have to use a Javascript based framework (Angular, Vue, React, NextJS, ...) and configure it as a public OAuth2 client (with the help of a library) for browser requests to be authorized with access tokens. Another (lately prefered) way to secure requests from Javascript application to resource servers is to insert a middleware on the server (a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend) to hide OAuth2 tokens from Javascript code. In this architecture, the BFF is the OAuth2 client and is responsible for replacing session cookie with an access token before forwarding requests from the browser to the REST API.

Resource server don't care about login, logout or how tokens were obtained or are kept. All that matter to it is if a request is authorized with an access token, if this access token is valid, if it was emitted by an authorization server it trusts and if he should grant access to the requested resources based on token claims.

The resource server configuration above is mostly inoperant and would accept only tokens emitted by the `realmuser` (provided that you write a client which sends such tokens because, as exposed above, your browser won't if it uses Spring's `oauth2Login`). **Whatever you'll try with `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` will have no effect on requests secured with sessions** (it applies to requests to resource servers, secured with JWT access tokens).

So, the first questions you should answer are those:

- Are you exposing a REST API you want to be secured with access tokens? If yes, those endpoints should be configured with OAuth2 resource server security
- Do you expose a templated UI (Thymeleaf or whatever)? If yes, those endpoints should be configured with OAuth2 client security
- Do you expose both a REST API and a UI to query it? In which case I strongly advise you split client and resource server configurations in distinct security filter-chains (one with client security based on sessions and the other with resource server security based on access tokens)

Once you get a clearer idea of your needs about OAuth2 clients and resource servers (and understood how different the security for the two are), I suggest you refer to the [tutorials I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), all support multiple authorization servers (or realms).

Comment: Actually I have a Vue.js client for frontend and several microservices for backend.
All microservices are protected by one realm, and one of them are to be protected by two realms - first for users and second for admins.
And all of their enpoints configured with OAuth2 client security.

So, is it a bad practice to protect endpoints for backend with OAuth2 client security?
As I understood from your explanation, it should be resource server security, is it?
And thanks a lot for the tutorials link - I'm going to study it carefully :)

Comment: REST APIs are generally configured as resource-servers. You might configure it as client to emulate a BFF without gateway, but at the cost of inter micro services communication: APIs will accept only requests from a browser with a session and not from a server side application (with an access token). So I'd advise you go with resource server micro services + gateway configured as BFF.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. But if my microservices do not communicate to each other via REST? They communicate to each other via Kafka. Would it be OK configure them as client?

Comment: Do you intend to maintain one session (and one user authentication) per micro-service? Do you intend to maintain sessions in Kafka?

Comment: No, Kafka wont't have any sessions. Actually I didn't think about sessions per micro-services, but now I realized that with my configuration a new session is created for each microservice, e.g. if I make a request to one microservice and after that I make a request to another microservice, every time is created a new session. Of course it would be better if I can maintain one session for all my microservices. So I can do it if I configure them as resource-servers. Is it correct?

Comment: First paragraph of the answer: resource servers are generally configured as stateless (no session). Requests security context is built from access token, not restored from session.